# JSF f:validateDoubleRange minimum="0" not working as expected

Tags: validation, jsf

I have the following code within a JSF/Richfaces project:

```
<h:inputText id="myValue" label="myValue" value="#{MyMB.value}">
  <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="0" />
  <rich:validator />
</h:inputText>
<rich:message for="myValue" />
```

Now this lets me enter `-1`, but not something like `"bla bla bla"`.
As far as I know `-1` is less than `0` so I'm confused about this behavior.

Entering

```
<f:validateDoubleRange minimum="0.0" />
```

does not fix this, but

```
<f:validateDoubleRange minimum="0.01" />
```

does. Now I'm no more allowed to enter `-1` but sadly also not `0` (a valid number in my case).

Does anyone know what this is about and how to get it right?

Comment: Where? I do not see that phenomenon happening (using Mojarra 2.2.12). `<f:validateDoubleRange>` does its job exactly as expected. What JSF implementation version do you happen to use? What is the type of the bean property being bound to the value bound expression?

Comment: Since I have to use Glassfish 3.1.2.2 I'm using Mojarre 2.1.6 and richfaces 4.3.7.Final. The type of the property is "Double"

Comment: This may be a possible bug in that JSF implementation version. You could upgrade it to a relatively newer Mojarra version (2.1.xx) in that version of GlassFish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code fixed it - but I agree with Tiny: it might be a bug ...

`<h:inputText id="myValue" label="myValue" value="#{MyMB.value}">
      <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="0" />
      <a4j:ajax status="status" event="change"
            execute="@this" render="myValue" />
      <rich:validator />
    </h:inputText>
    <rich:message for="myValue" />`